# Programatically enable and navigate to full screen apps in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-settings

1. In the Android Phone-Samsung there is an option in settings called
   `Full-screen apps`
2. On click of it we have options `Auto` and `Full screen`

---

Questions

1. Is there a way we can programmatically check this from the app
2. How to navigate the user for this page for particular app selections
   from an app with the click of a button

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for question 1:**

I think you can use this flag **WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN** like this:

```
val fullScreenApp = (window.attributes.flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)!= 0
```

**Answer for question 2:**

**Note** - both package names here are for example find the ones you need first and replace.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.component = ComponentName(
    "com.samsung.android.Settings", // application package
    "com.samsung.android.Settings.Widget.FullScreenAppActivity" // Activity package
)


try {
    startActivity(intent)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // Custom error handling
}
```

**N.B:** - be aware that both package names can change over time so keep them up to date or make a dynamic package name search.

Comment: There is a settings options in samsung phones where you can change options as I posted in image ... I want to check if the option is full screen is set if not ... i am trying to have a code block to navigate to that page

Comment: With the code from my answer you can check that without navigating to this setting's page.

Comment: @Top40 ... I have upvoted for that input ... Any place I can find the correct snippet to navigate?

Comment: This code takes the user to the Display Settings page But is not specific to the screen I showed above. it comes one level later
 .
`fun navigateToDisplaySettings() = startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS))`

Comment: Sorry buddy I was away for the weekend. If you have find a solution yet you can try to route the users directly to the system Full Screen App Activity. I am not sure whats the package name of the activity but will add an edit to my answer with a basic example how to to that. Hope it helps you!